# Adding a realm in Websphere Linux 8.5.5.4 Server

Tags: realm, ibm-mobilefirst

Need a help on how to add a realm for a example.
            
                         com.worklight.integration.auth.AdapterAuthenticator

How should i put this realm to server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's got nothing to do with your application server.

You define Realms in the MobileFirst project that you created using either  MobileFirst Studio or the CLI tool (in which case you then edit a file in whichever code/text editor of your choosing).

In both cases the file to edit is called `authenticationConfig.xml` and is located in the `your-project\server\conf\` folder.

Before touching this file, though, you should familiar yourself with the authentication concept in MobileFirst Platform because you do not simply "add a realm". You are required to also configure its associated Login Module and security tests as well as actually utilize it somewhere in your application's logic.

Please read:

- Developer Center: [Authentication and Security](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/authentication-security/)
- Knowledge Center: [MobileFirst Security Framework](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_6.3.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/r_security_framework.html)

The tutorials and documentations topic above will also lead you to Adapter-based authentication, which is what you are supposedly actually looking for.

Comment: I found out the authenticationConfig.xml and declare all service realm ,also loginmodule another problem came out thought.